# Pass non-static parameter to filter in CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

In my application, I have a database-like structure, where the database object itself contains several `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Guid, T>>` collections. The `Guid`s act similar to primary keys in a relational database, i.e., they provide 1:1 and 1:n mappings between objects of the different collections (“tables” in database-ese).

Now consider binding the `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Guid, T>>` that is at the root of the object hierarchy in an `ItemsControl`. Inside the `DataTemplate`, I want to *bind a subset* of another of the collections to a `DependencyProperty` of a `UserControl`, where the `Guid`s match values that each of the objects in the first collection carry.

As a plethora of answers here on SO suggest, a `CollectionViewSource` is what I need, i.e.,

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RootObjectCollection}>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <local:CustomUserControl>
        <local:CustomUserControl.SubsetCollection>
          <Binding>
            <Binding.Source>
              <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding DataContext.Database.SubsetCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                    Filter="someFilter"
                               ???? FilterParameters="{Binding SelectedKeys}" />
            </Binding.Source>
          </Binding>
        </local:CustomUserControl.SubsetCollection>
      </local:CustomUserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

However, I need to dynamically pass a parameter of type `ObservableCollection<Guid>` to the filter of the `CollectionViewSource`.

I’m frankly lost, since the documentation doesn’t have anything on this. I can’t believe that I’m the first one in need of a parameterized dynamic filter that doesn’t bind to a text field… Any hint is greatly appreciated!

#### Update 2019-03-18

The above code should now be a little clearer. Aside from that, some more background information so as to clarify @erotavlas’s questions:

- The code above resides in a view with its own view model as data context. The `CustomUserControl` that is instantiated within the `DataTemplate` has its own view model, too. What I try above is passing the filter result (which is a subset of the `SubsetCollection` based on a primary key indicator contained in the `ItemControl`’s current `RootObjectCollection` element) to the `CustomUserControl`’s corresponding field.
- All of the `ObservableCollection`s reside within the surrounding view’s view model in an object called `Database`. This object contains several of those `ObservableCollections`, among others, `RootObjectCollection` and `SubsetCollection`.

Comment: How is your user control datacontext set? To it's own viewmodel or does it inherit the datacontext of the parent control? And where does each observablecollection reside?

Comment: @erotavlas, I’ve updated my question so as to clarify what you’re asking. Please have a look and thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I need to dynamically pass a parameter of type `ObservableCollection<Guid>` to the filter of the `CollectionViewSource`.

`CollectionViewSource.Filter` is an event and you can't pass any custom parameters to it. You get a `FilterEventArgs` that has a read-only reference to the item and an `Accepted` property that you can set to indicate whether to include the item in the filtered set, but that's it.

You could perhaps consider to create a class that extends `CollectionViewSource` and add your own custom [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) it. This should enable you to bind to a source property like `SelectedKeys`. You can then retrieve the value of the dependency property by casting the `sender` argument in the `Filter` event handler, e.g.:

```
private void Cvs_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    YourCustomCollectionViewSource cvs = sender as YourCustomCollectionViewSource;
    //..
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Due to time pressure, I had to walk a path I knew and found a [perfectly feasible workaround solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55318798/3517056). I didn’t implement your suggestion, but since it a) appears feasible, and b) is a direct answer to my question (as opposed to my own workaround), I accept yours as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

When I posted this question, I was in a hurry since only a few days were missing before a very important demo (financing round of the product). Since I couldn’t figure out how to approach the problem with `CollectionViewSource`, I decided to try a solution using the old `MultiValueConverter` approach, all while being fully aware that this would have me create a new `ObservableCollection` of the subset collection’s values, which—according to the [C# man page for `ObservableCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T>`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) would only work one-way since “the elements are copied onto the `ObservableCollection<T>`”. I thought that it’d be better to show that the view is filled from the database without reflecting back changes into the database, than to show nothing at all.

Imagine my surprise when it turned out that the man page is not entirely correct here: only primitive values are copied, wile complex objects are passed by reference into the new `ObservableCollection<T>`! This means that the following snippet is an entirely valid solution to my problem:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RootObjectCollection}>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <local:CustomUserControl>
        <local:CustomUserControl.SubsetCollection>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SubsetEntryFromRootObjectIdSelectionConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Value.SubsetIds" />
            <Binding Path="DataContext.Database.SubsetCollection" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}" />
        </MultiBinding>
        </local:CustomUserControl.SubsetCollection>
      </local:CustomUserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The important part here is the `MultiValueConverter` itself, which is defined as

```
public class SubsetEntryFromRootObjectIdSelectionConverter: IMultiValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      if (values[0] == null) // no reference ids contained
        return new ObservableCollection<SubsetItem>();

      if (!(values[0] is ObservableCollection<Guid>))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Value must be a collection of Guids.");

      if (!(values[1] is ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Guid, SubsetItem>>))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Value must be a collection of SubsetItems.");

      var selectedKeys = (ObservableCollection<Guid>)values[0];
      var originalCollection = (ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Guid, SubsetItem>>)values[1];
      var queryCollection = originalCollection.Where(kvp => selectedKeys.Contains(kvp.Key)).Select(kvp => kvp.Value);

      // it seems that the man page is misleading and that this constructor indeed copies references, not objects
      return new ObservableCollection<SubsetItem>(queryCollection);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

Since this solution works flawlessly, I didn’t implement [the one suggested by @mm8 above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222192/3517056). However, technically speaking, the suggested solution is a direct answer to my question, whereas mine is, being honest, rather a workaround. Therefore, I’ll accept @mm8’s answer instead of mine.